# Inner HTML on infobox z-index - infobox goes under the pins

Tags: bing-maps, pushpin

Got a map V7 and a layer of pushpins as an entity collection.

Here is the crazy part:
When I pop an infobox without innerHtml set then it pops "over" the pushpins. 
When I pop the infobox with my inner HTML is pops under the pushpin entity collection.

I have  z-indexed my innerhtml as 100 etc to go higher than all,

It seems as if the pushpin entity layer is on a differnent level,

Any ideas?

(I have tried to set the infobox on other entity collection - and it did pop on top of the pushpins - but then the innerHtml did not respond)

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem and solved it by:

- setting the z-index to 4000
- using absolute position

Here is my infobox html code:

```
<div id="infoboxText" style="z-index: 4000; position:absolute; font-size: 20px; background-color:White; min-height:50px;width:250px;"><div>
```